# 'ascii' code cant encode character '\xe7' in position

Tags: python, ascii

tengo una variable "Besançon Mobilités"

que tengo que detectar como tal con ese texto, para introducirla como nombre de algo en una consola, el problema es que me da el error del título, por los carácteres, alguna solución para esto?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca un pequeño código (mínimo) que ilustre el problema, pues no está claro cual es tu propósito.

Comment: Ese texto ¿de dónde te llega? ¿Lo lees de un fichero externo, lo mete el usuario con un input, lo recibes de la red? ¿O por el contrario lo tienes ya asignado en tu código a una variable y sólo necesitas imprimirlo? En el segundo caso ¿en qué operativo lo ejecutas? ¿ qué versión de python?

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
u'Besançon Mobilités'
```

De ese modo le dices al intérprete de python que la cadena de texto contiene caracteres no ascii

Comment: El prefijo "u" para string Unicode no se requiere desde Python 3.0. Usarlo o no hace diferencia alguna. Deberías explicar eso del Unicode, Python 2.x y 3.x.